# Recursive differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

EDIT 1/2:

My apologies.. I did not look back at it ...now rewritten..

Take a particular odd solution of $ y′′(x)+y(x)=0 $ as $\sin (x)$. Plug $\sin(x)$ in place of $y(x)$, where we non-linearized $x$ *and* swapped $y$ for $x$ resulting in $y′′(x)+\sin(y)=0$

Next similarly take an odd solution of $y′′(x)+\sin(y)=0 $ from which choose BC to get an odd elliptic function say $ S_1(x) $ after argument changed, with first maximum value of solution set to 1. Plug this in place of $\sin(y(x))$ making a new differential equation  $ y′′(x)+S_1(y(x))=0 $

Continue this iteration procedure ad infinitum ... Does $ y′′(x)+S_n(y(x))=0 $ converge to some highly non-linear function?...can we see a plot of the successive "super" sin functions so generated? ( Just as we can see plots of $\sin(x)$ for one,two three ...$\infty$) number of terms?

Comment: What do you mean by "plug it in place of y" exactly? You are only replacing $y$ by $\sin(y)$ but not $y''$.

Comment: I mean in $ y''  = -y ; y'' = - sin(y) $ etc. plug into the right hand side of equation only.

Comment: In which sense is sin(y) a solution of y''+y=0?

Comment: @Narasimham I made a big edit. Please check that it's not entirely out of line with your intention (and edit or rollback if it's not what you wanted)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Meelo. "iteration" exactly gives it.

Comment: The equation $y''(x) + \sin(x) =0$ is solved with $y=\sin(x)$. Further iteration won't create anything new either.

Comment: Thanks @IvanNeretin. Shall delete this for the time being, until I am able to better define a proper recursion method.

Comment: @IvanNeretin. Does it at least as a question sound good?

Comment: "with argument changed of first maximum value =1": this is not English. Can you rephrase.

Comment: Now that's a different story. I don't know if the answer is nice, but at least the question makes sense.

Comment: @ Yves Daoust Pl see if it says it..